# MobileAds.initialize() and IntersitialAd.loadAd() StrictModePolicy violation

Tags: android, admob

I have some ANR's error reported on Google Play Console. 
I turn on Strict Mode like this:

```
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());
```

And I've noticed violations only in AdMob method:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
```

and:

```
   interstitialAd.loadAd(adReqest);
```

Error logs on MobileAds.initialize():

```
StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=827 ms: 
android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation:
```

and on InterstitialAd.loadAd():

```
stack=android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeCustomViolation: 
policy=4259871 violation=8 msg=gcore.dynamite
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onCustomSlowCall(StrictMode.java:1280)
    at android.os.StrictMode.noteSlowCall(StrictMode.java:2225)
```

I'd like to ask if have anybody discovered that issues?
If yes, is it possible that errors can provide to ANR's?
How to remove this issues?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930737/adview-loadad-triggering-a-strictmode-violation

Comment: It should be noted that the referenced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930737/adview-loadad-triggering-a-strictmode-violation is only offering an answer to the violation about the disk reads. It does not offer an answer on the second part, the slow UI calls.